# rosserial Fuerte install help [Solved]

Tags: rosserial, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: Managed to download from source and install without issue. Had to restart as updates were preventing connections.

Hey

I am currently trying to install rosserial for ROS Fuerte, and I keep getting that rosserial can not be found.

From everything I have seen it should exist, however following instructions from http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup do not seem to be working.

Trying to download from debs I get the following.

robot@robot:~$ **sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-rosserial**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-diamondback-rosserial

Trying to install from source, I am new'ish to Ubunutu so this error I think is as simple as me missing something.

robot@robot:~$ **hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial**
abort: error: no host given

What steps am I missing to download rosserial correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45148/rosserial-fuerte-install-help-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @HenryW 's edit:

Managed to download from source and install without issue. Had to restart as updates were preventing connections.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0